# Open facebook page in app from webapp mobile

Tags: android, ios, facebook, onclick

I want to open a facebook page on iOS and android from a webapp. 
fb://profile/535206246624612 works for iOS but won't work for android.
How do i set something up to work for both operating systems.

This is how I want to launch the facebook page:

```
...
<li id="facebook" onclick="fb://profile/535206246624612" >
  <div>
    <img class="icon" src="icons/connect.png">
    <p>Facebook ></p>
  </div>
</li>
...
```

Comment: This is not recommended as you can never be sure that the app is installed on the device. You should link to the www.facebook.com url instead.

Comment: We don't officially support deep linking into the Facebook for iOS app so it's best not to do this or your app will break sooner or later.